# How to keep Placeholders even after clearing all textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

So I have 3 textfields. After they are cleared, I would like the placeholder to **STILL** remain there. So far for about the past week I've been fighting with this issue and no one is able to help me solve it. I was wondering if this is even possible?...

Here is my sample code to set the placeholder after clearing it:

```
personYouOweMoney.text = @" ";
amtYouOwe.text = @" ";
self.cellNum.text = @" ";

personYouOweMoney.placeholder = @"Name of person you owe";
amtYouOwe.placeholder = @"Amount Owed (USD)";
self.cellNum.placeholder = @"Their cell number";
```

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: you are assigning space to your textfields which is treated as string, instead use self.cellNum.text = @""; and so..

Answer (score 5):

You are basically setting the `textField`'s text to a single space so, technically, it ain't empty.
*(Only when the `textField` is empty will the placeholder will be seen*)

Do:

```
//set the placeholder's and when you want to clear the textfield, this...
personYouOweMoney.text = @"";
amtYouOwe.text = @"";
self.cellNum.text = @"";
```

Comment: I can accept your answer in 8 minutes! I actually Im really tired and gonna take a break then go to bed, but first thing in the morning before I upload my app to the App Store I'll mark your answer with that green check :)

Comment: @doc92606 so have you woken up yet to mark his answer? :)